# Tkinter pack with anchor/side not filling all available space

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.master)
        self.notebook.pack(side="top", anchor="n", expand=True)

        # create tabs
        self.tabs = {}
        self.tabs["tab1"] = tk.Frame(self.notebook, width=420, height=420, borderwidth=0)
        self.tabs["tab2"] = tk.Frame(self.notebook, width=420, height=420, borderwidth=0)
        self.tab_headers = ["tab1", "tab2"]

        self.tabs["tab1"].pack()
        self.tabs["tab2"].pack()

        # add frame with label below notebook
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="#ffff00")
        self.bottom_frame.pack(side="top", anchor="n", fill="x")

        self.bottom_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_frame, text="This is a label below the notebook", font=("TkDefaultFont", 14), bg="#ffff00")
        self.bottom_label.pack(side="top", pady=10)

        # add tabs to notebook
        self.notebook.add(self.tabs["tab1"], text='Tab 1')
        self.notebook.add(self.tabs["tab2"], text='Tab 2')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("420x840")
root.resizable(False, False)

app = App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

How do you get the frame/label below the notebook to be packed directly below the notebook? Even after trying side=top and anchor=n, it still aligns to the bottom of the window, even when there is clearly enough room for it to be aligned further up.

[image]

Even after trying side=top and anchor=n, it still aligns to the bottom of the window, even when there is clearly enough room for it to be aligned further up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have used `expand=True` in `self.notebook.pack(...)`, so the notebook will use all the available space and the bottom frame will be pushed to the bottom of the window.

If you just use `self.notebook.pack()`, then the bottom frame will be just below the notebook:

[image]